# C# Windows Application vs Console Application Causing Differences to Process.Start()

Tags: c#, python, .net, winforms, process

I have a C# GUI wrapper that is using Process.Start() to call various third party python scripts (these scripts cannot be changed). The relevant code:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = FileParserConstants.PYTHON_PATH; // Path to python exe
process.StartInfo.Arguments = FileParserConstants.SCRIPT_PATH + sInput; // Path to scripts with input script + arguments
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();

return process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().Trim();
```

This seems relatively simple, and it works when my C# project type is set to "Windows Application." However, upon switching to a "Console Application," though there is no error, the python scripts fail to function as intended.

Namely, there is a python script that accepts arguments and calls an exe to change settings given the arguments. When the python script is called from the project set as Console Application, a "OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid" occurs within the exe called from within the python (this error is handled within the python scripts and logged). Again, when the script is called from the project set as Windows Application, it functions correctly.

For reasons unreleated to the issue, I am being forced to have this project be a Console Application, and am having trouble finding the documentation of the differences between the two project types and what may be causing Process to behave differently.

Comment: As you said, the exe wants to acquire a handle but fails, if you invoke it from a console application process. That makes me think, the type of handle the exe is trying to acquire is a window handle, which it obviously would not be able to get from a console application process. Since i don't know the exe, neither its precise concrete purpose and function nor any commandline arguments that it supports (nor any concrete commandline arguments you are feeding to it), i can't help any further... :(

Comment: I do not believe the exe's purpose or arguments are relevant to the issue (they are in house and proprietary, unfortunately). Suffice to say even I'm not sure what the exe the python script is calling is actually doing to change settings. For a little more information, I can run the same exact python command from a command prompt window and have it work, which is why I was expecting the console application to function fine. Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: Well, if it is an inhouse exe and you are unable or not allowed to share information about, then no one here can really help you. Coming up with a possible solution to make it run with a console application (if there would be any such solution) would require at least some basic understanding of what the exe actually does and/or how its behavior can be modified to address your problem. :(

Comment: I'm mostly just trying to understand the issue - *why* does running this python script function differently as a Console Application compared to from a Command Prompt window, the "Run" command, or as a Windows application? In all three of the latter cases the script functions as intended by the writers. Do Console Applications not have a similar handle to a script run from the command prompt?

Comment: You are looking at the wrong place. The problem is with the exe and/or the involved Python scripts perhaps). The Process class does not behave differently. It always does exactly the same thing, independent of the C# project type you did choose. To solve your problem, you will have to get an understanding of what the exe actually does and what handle it specifically is trying to acquire. Either the exe does look for the source of the handle all by itself, or it is told by the caller (Python script) what the source is.

Comment: You are asking us here to wildly speculate about the two things that are the reasons for the problem - the exe and the Python script(s) - and we know absolutely _nothing_ about. You are asking us to play a game of pinning the tail on the donkey... (It might be a window handle thing, it might be somthing related to the current working directory, it might be something entirely else... who knows!) There is nothing we can do to help you under these circumstances. I am sorry i can't tell what the (technical) cause of your problem is, but i don't have a crystal ball... :-(

Comment: The difference between the two scenarios is the type of message pumping that the application is doing in the console app vs the windows app.  I don't know of any interaction between Process.WaitForExit() and the message pumping nor do I understand the requirements for your python environment.  But I think that would be the place for you to look.  Here's something you might look into https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2005-August/304273.html